# creating dataframe from directory, columns should be subdirectories

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a dataframe from many csv's which are located in subdirectories.

The dataframe should contain the data from all files in a subdirectory, and each column should contain the data from the next subdir, and should be named after this subdir.

I have come far but now I'm stuck. This is what i have written so far:

```
rootdir = 'D:/Favorites/Michiel/Studie/Master/PV data/CSV/15min/DDW'
yield_current_day = 'Energy Yield of Current Day (kWh)'
inv = []
frame = pd.DataFrame()
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files: 
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir, file),
                encoding='UTF-16', header=1, sep='\t',
                index_col='Generated On', parse_dates=True)
        df = df[yield_current_day]
        df = df.to_frame()
        df=df.rename(columns={yield_current_day:str(subdir)[-3:]})
        df = df.sort_index()
        inv.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(inv)
```

however this yields me a frame with the right columns and data, but the first column contains the data of the first subfolder, and after that 3 (there are 3 subfolders in this case) duplicates of the index with NaN values.

The second column starts with one duplicate of the index with NaN values, then the data, and then 2 duplicates with NaNs. this continues to the last subdir.

`Dropna` doesnt work because all columns contain NaNs and all rows do as well.

I have tried `drop_duplicates` but this also removes the date I need. I think I need to change the `for file in files` to `for subdirs in dir` or something?

Or maybe find a way to delete the duplicates in the `for` loop or try to prevent the `for` loop from creating them in the first place.

Comment: Have a look at your `inv` collection, particularly `len(inv)`. It looks like you should have each file as a separate item in the list, but all the files in a directory will end up with the same column name: check your line `df.rename(columns=...)`, and you'll see there's no reference to a filename there.

Comment: inv contains a dataframe of each file. the columns are named after the subdirs. If i can find a way to get the data from each subdir in a seperate list, i'll be fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. Each directory contains many files, correct? But the columns are named after the subdirectory. Doesn't that mean that many files will end up with the same column name?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want. Each subdirectory contains many files. I want all the data from a subdirectory in a column named after this subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

Worked around this by editing the 'wrong' dataframe by adding:

```
    df = pd.concat(inv)

ls = []
for column in df:
framec = df[column]
framec = framec.dropna()
framec = framec[~framec.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
ls.append(framec)
totalframe = pd.concat(ls, axis = 1)
totalframe = totalframe.dropna()
```

totalframe now is what i want!